# Is there any way to create an iTunes smart playlist with a user defined text field as the condition?

Tags: itunes, applescript, metadata, playlist, id3-tag

I'm using iTunes 12.8 with Yate by 2manyrobots (https://2manyrobots.com/yate/) to manage metadata for a library of approx 50k AIFF tracks.

Yate has the ability to retrieve data from Discogs and write to ID3 tags - in doing so it writes the unique Discogs Release ID to a User Defined Text field.

What I want to do is create a live updating smart playlist in iTunes that can tell me which tracks do not have a Discogs Release ID so that I can process them, but obviously I cannot set User Defined Text fields as a condition on the smart playlist.

Is there any way around this? Perhaps using an AppleScript that I can run periodically which can inspect the metadata and create a playlist..?

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't have a solution for you but thanks for bringing Yate to my attention. Wicked good software. I've been looking for an app like this for a while.

Comment: no worries - yep it's superb

Comment: I doubt it, since to me it seems like Yate is writing to its own database.  iTunes can't retrieve that field because it doesn't know how to access Yate's information.  I suppose you could have a go-between field that's native to iTunes and write that AppleScript, but it might turn into a nightmare to complain.